# Guice - Jersey - Servlet binding

Tags: java, servlets, jersey, guice

I recently switched to two phase injection and this has created an error in my servlet binding.  I am currently toggling between two error modes and not sure which direction is best to pursue.

The first error I encountered was:

> com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig
>   instance does not contain any root resource classes.

My servlet module looked like this:

```
public class MyServletModule extends JerseyServletModule {
    @Override
    protected void configureServlets() {
        bind(MyServlet.class).asEagerSingleton();

        serve("/*").with(GuiceContainer.class);
    }
}
```

I was able to remove this error by explicitly providing the com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages parameter.

```
public class MyServletModule extends JerseyServletModule {

    @Override
    protected void configureServlets() {
        bind(MyServlet.class).asEagerSingleton();

        Map<String,String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
        parameters.put(PackagesResourceConfig.PROPERTY_PACKAGES, MyServlet.class.getPackage().getName());
        serve("/*").with(GuiceContainer.class, parameters);
    }
}
```

But when I do this, Guice attempts a Just in Time binding which does not respect the @Inject on my servlet constructor.

> com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:
>
> 1) Unable to create binding for MyServlet. It was already configured
>   on one or more child injectors or private modules
>       bound at MyServletModule.configureServlets(MyServletModule.java:44)   If it was
>   in a PrivateModule, did you forget to expose the binding?   while
>   locating MyServlet
>
> 1 error   at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBinding(InjectorImpl.java:150)

My servlet has an @Inject constructor who's arguments cannot be bound just in time.  After debugging into InjectorImpl, I believe this is the reason that things fail when I use PROPERTY_PACKAGES.

I'm just not sure if using PROPERTY_PACKAGES is correct and I need to fix some bindings?  Or if that is the wrong direction and I need to fix the original ResourceConfig error in a different way.

Help or a push in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to bind Jersey resources to Guice without using the bind-parameters (without explicitly providing the com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages parameter), by binding resources separately

```
public class BindJerseyResources extends ServletModule {

    @Override
    protected void configureServlets() {
        // excplictly bind GuiceContainer before binding Jersey resources
        // otherwise resource won't be available for GuiceContainer
        // when using two-phased injection
        bind(GuiceContainer.class);

        // bind Jersey resources
        PackagesResourceConfig resourceConfig = new PackagesResourceConfig("jersey.resources.package");
        for (Class<?> resource : resourceConfig.getClasses()) {
            bind(resource);
        }

        // Serve resources with Jerseys GuiceContainer
        serve("/*").with(GuiceContainer.class);
    }
}
```

The resources are like following

```
@Path("/")
@RequestScoped
public class Resource {

    private Storage storage;

    @Inject
    public Resource(Storage storage) {
        this.storage = storage;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("get/{name}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getGuid(@PathParam("name") String name) {
        return storage.get(name);
    }
}
```

Maybe this helps you to avoid the latter problematic binding.

---

Updated the answer to work with two-phased injection.

Comment: This seems to identify my servlets in their package, I get an info level log saying "INFO: Root resource classes found:" but then later I still get the error "com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes."

Comment: Strange, i didn't have any such exceptions from using `GuiceContainer`. I extracted example from the project from which the above code snippets are. Maybe that helps you to solve the problem (if the problem is caused for example by some version of Jersey or Guice)

Example is in Github: https://github.com/reap/jetty-guice-jersey-example

Comment: That's a great example, I can easily reproduce my issue if I convert the code in InitializeGuiceModulesContextListener to use 2-phase injection like this: return Guice.createInjector(new BindServicesModule()).createChildInjector(new BindJerseyResourcesModule());  Obviously in this case use of 2-phase injection is forced just for demonstration purposes, but I actually need it in my case.

Comment: Thanks, now I can reproduce the error also. The problem seems to be that the Injector given to `GuiceContainer` does not contain the Jersey-resource, and seems to me that the Injector given `GuiceContainer` is in fact the parent injector (the one createad by `Guice.createInjector(new BindServicesModule())` and not the childInjector), because the injector which ends up in `GuiceModule` does not have a parent.

Comment: David B. actually solved this problem in (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454647/jersey-guice-doesnt-process-bound-resources-if-injector-is-a-child) You need to explictly bind the `GuiceContainer` before binding the resources. I updated the [example in github](https://github.com/reap/jetty-guice-jersey-example/tree/two-phased-injection), which now works using the two-phased injection (change is in its own branch). I also updated the answer.

Comment: Actually you don't have to bind the `GuiceContainer` before resources, but it must be explicitly bound in same injector where the resources are used. This probably has something to do with the way Jersey digs resource bindings from injector (it browses through all binds and selects resources from them) instead of asking Guice to inject them.

Comment: Explicitly binding the GuiceContainer has resolved this issue.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Java Part

```
import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Injector;
import com.google.inject.Singleton;
import com.google.inject.persist.jpa.JpaPersistModule;
import com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceServletContextListener;
import com.sun.jersey.guice.JerseyServletModule;
import com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.servlet.GuiceContainer;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer;
import com.thjug.apipublic.Echo;

public class ServletContextListener extends GuiceServletContextListener {

    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector() {
        final Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new JerseyServletModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configureServlets() {
                bind(Echo.class);
                bind(ServletContainer.class).in(Singleton.class);
                serve("/*").with(GuiceContainer.class);
            }
        }, new JpaPersistModule("dbUnit"), new LoggingModule());

        injector.getInstance(JPAInitializer.class);
        return injector;
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
    <distributable />

    <display-name>API</display-name>

    <filter>
            <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
            <description>Guice Initiate</description>
            <listener-class>com.thjug.base.ServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Below is my keynote about How to make REST with Guice
http://www.slideshare.net/nuboat/lightweight-javaee

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article on how to do the binding (including full source code):
[implementing-distributed-counter](http://rrusin.blogspot.com/2014/07/implementing-distributed-counter.html)