# Shiro Guice and Jersey JAX-RS Filters order

Tags: java, jersey, guice, shiro, jersey-1.0

I am having a trouble with the Shiro Guice Filter ordering. The modules are registered like this:

```
@Override
protected Injector getInjector() {
    Module[] modules = { new RestServiceModule(), // my services module
            new MySecurityModule(context), // my wrapper around ShiroWebModule
            new MyJerseyServletModule() }; // my wrapper around JerseyServletModule
    logger.debug("Creating injector");
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(modules);

    return injector;
}

....

// MyJerseyServletModule
@Override
protected void configureServlets() {
    // Binding rest entry points
    bind(Hello.class);
    bind(Anon.class);
    // Setup GuiceContainer
    serve("/*").with(GuiceContainer.class);
    filter("/*").through(GuiceShiroFilter.class);
}
```

The problem is with the order filters are executed. GuiceShiroFilter is run before the Jersey JAX-RS filters (like @GET and @POST). In this case the request firstly trying to authenticate the user and after that validates the method (and send back "405 Method not allowed" for example).
I assume the transport protocol validation filters (Jersey filters in other words) should come in a first place. Am I missing something?

Comment: Recently I've successfully integrated Guice, Shiro and Jersey 1.x.
But I've used Shiro CAS module to integrate CAS authentication.
Shiro filter is a first-place filter in my configuration (right after GuiceFilter of course) which is configured by ShiroWebModule.guiceFilterModule() method call.
My "CasModule" is installed before "JerseyModule".

As far as I understand you are trying to protect Jersey's REST API using Shiro, aren't you?

Comment: Not exactly. I am trying to put Jersey filters in a first place, to check the method type (GET or POST) **before** Shiro checks authentication. For now it is vice versa, It checks the authentication and **after** that Jersey is telling me "405 Method Not Allowed".

Comment: For me it looks like incorrect Guice configuration.
Have you tried to bind GuiceContainer before REST endpoints?
This [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972198/guice-jersey-servlet-binding) has some useful point concerning proper Jersey/Guice configuration.